# ImportError: No module named pymysql on Mac OS

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pymysql

I am using Mac OS Mojave, I have a script which requires pymysql, it was running fine few weeks ago, but today when I try to run the script, it gave me the error as in the title, I tried to remove and reinstall pymysql, but the problem still persist, any other ways for me to solve it?

Comment: There is a folder named pymysql in the right place on your mac? /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymysql

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by installing `pymysql`:

```
python -m pip install PyMySQL
```

**NOTE:** You may have to do `sudo python -m pip install PyMySQL` to get around a permissions error.

**Reference:** https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/